# Radioactive Substance Decay Problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

A radioactive substance decays according to :

$$x' = -ax$$

where $a>0$ is a constant. After $2$ days there are $1,000$ grams and after $7$ days there are $300$ grams. How many grams were there initially?

I'm unsure how I'd go on with doing this, any help would be greatly appreciated...

Cheers.

EDIT: The step I got upto was separation of variables/integration:

$$x = e^{-at}$$

Comment: Hint: your equation says that $dx/dt = -ax$ so that $dx/x = -adt$.

Comment: Just what I was thinking! Separation of variables followed by integration :) please let me know if that is correct so far, thank you Eric!

Comment: Exactly. If you get stuck the answer is another very good hint.

Comment: Okay, so doing so, I get: x = e^(-at). How would I make the 2 equations though now since I have the data for 2 days = 1000 grams and 7 days = 300 grams. Thanks again!

Comment: Be very careful with your limits of integration--you cannot just use an anti-derivative. The equation should involve $x_0$, the amount of substance at $t=0$. Once you have the correct formula, plug in the values given (you are given $t$ and $x$ twice) to get two equations in two unknowns.

Comment: Hm, I am still at the part where I derived the equation... how would I go on with the next part now? I am a bit confused how to get the correct formulas for the 2 pieces of data. Thanks Eric.

Comment: You should edit the equation into your question, then we will have common symbols and can get on with it.

Comment: Okay, I edited the question but have trouble putting it in proper format ($$e^-at$$)

Comment: To get multicharacter exponents, put them in braces.  e^{-at} gives $e^{-at}$  This works for subscripts and items in fractions, as well.

Comment: Regarding your solution in the question (idk if you posted that before or after Ross' answer): Don't forget your +C when integrating...

Comment: Good point, yeah, but I am still stuck at the equation. Not sure where to go next on how to form the two separate equations for each of the cases. Can anyone help ? Thanks for all your responses guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you solve the differential equation?  You should have a solution with two constants-the initial amount and $a$.  The two pieces of data give you two equations in two unknowns to find these constants.

Added:  your solution needs a constant of integration.  The solution should be $x=c\cdot e^{-at}$.  Now plug in the data you are given: $$1000=c\cdot e^{-2a}\\300=c \cdot e^{-7a}$$  Now solve those for $a,c$ and $x(0)$ is just $c$

Comment: Would I do a separation of variables and then integrate both sides to find a general equation ? Hope you can answer, thanks for your reply mate.

Comment: Yes, that is a fine approach.

Comment: Great edit, how would you move onto solving? Would I just divide the two first? Hope you can respond again, thanks for your quality response.

Comment: Yes, if you divide them, $c$ goes away and you can solve for $a$. Put that $a$ into one and you can solve for $c$.

Comment: Hey Ross, great response. I got the value of a but I'm unsure if it would make a difference if I inputted that value into either of the equations? Because if I input into one or the other, they both have different values. Hope you can answer, that should be my last inquiry. Thanks!

Comment: @user101985 If you get different results for $c$ with the value of $a$ you solved for, you have the wrong value of $a$. In fact, solving for $a$ can be seen as finding the values of $a$ that makes both equations true for the same value of $c$. It should not matter which equation. You should have done $1000/300 = (c \cdot e^{-2a}) / (c \cdot e^{-7a}) = e^{-2a} e^{7a} = e^{5a}$ and then taken the natural logarithm to solve for $a$.

Comment: This gives $a \approx 0.24079$, then $e^{2a}\approx 0.6178$, so $c\approx 1618$.  Checking, $1618e^{-7\cdot0.24079}\approx 299.89$